# New definition for triangle wave?

Tags: graphing-functions

There's always a huge formula for the triangle wave, or the "teeth" function as I like to call it. Shouldn't this give a teeth function too? It's sorta hard to understand, but once you get the hang of it, it works out fine. This one produces $(-2,2), (0,0), (2,2), (4,0)$, etc.

$f(x) = |x-4k|$, where $4k-2 \leq x \leq 4k+2$ and $k$ is an integer. Plug in different $k$ values $(0, 1, 2, etc)$

Comment: I always use $\Delta(x)=\frac{\arcsin(\cos(2\pi f x))}{\pi}$ for a frequency, $f$, if this is ever useful to you in the future

Answer (score 3):

You are right: this formula defines a triangular wave. It's certainly nothing  new, though.

An even shorter formula for the same function can be given using the concept of distance from a point to a set: 
$$f(x)=\operatorname{dist}(x,4\mathbb Z)$$

But the above is not likely to be understood by a computer, if you want to use it for graphing. In that case, I would go for something like
$$f(x)= \Big|x-4 \lfloor x/4+1/2\rfloor\Big|$$
[Tested in WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+abs%28x-4%2afloor%28x%2F4%2B1%2F2%29%29+from+-10+to+10)